# I want to hit url of another application in a yii framework application.How to do that?

Tags: php, url, yii

I want to hit url of another application in a yii framework application.How to do that?

I can do it in my own app like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
        <?php echo CHtml::link('Agent', $this->createUrl('/agent/agent/admin')); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

But I want to hit some url outside by application. How to do that?

Comment: Use cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php There are plenty of good examples of how to use this on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the super simple `file_get_contents()` if you just want to hit the url?

```
<?php file_get_contents('http://www.example.com'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca use this

```
CHtml::link( CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/android.png'),('http://www.google.com'), array('class'=>" "));
```

Comment: I am running my application in localhost. it goes to http://localhost/www.google.com . Do you know how to prevent it?

Comment: Is there any way that I will only retrive the data from the other url by not going to it and save it to database? I am sorry for asking too many questions. I am really new about the things. Your help is appriciated.

Comment: I cannot understand what you're asking, trying to explain the issue further

Comment: this will ridirect to that page. but I want if one click the link only the response will be stored in databse. but in view no redirection will be happened.